# Prove the determinant of a 2x2 block matrix can be opened with the regular determinant formula

Tags: matrices

Let $A, B, C, D \in M_n(F)$, such that $C$ and $D$ are invertible and $CD=DC$.

Prove:

\begin{vmatrix}
A & B \\ 
C & D
\end{vmatrix} = $|AD - BC|$

What is the direction? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? How about $n=1$ and $n=2$?

Comment: $n=1$ is by definition. Are you hinting for induction?

Comment: I am just hinting that you should show more of what you have tried.